# I have issues creating a hyperlink in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy a sheet in Excel, name it and then creating a hyperlink to the created sheet. Copy and name it is not a problem but I cant seem to get the Hyperlink to work. Would anybody know where the error is?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Kind regards 
Matt

```
Sub CreateSheet()

    Dim wst As Worksheet
    Dim strProjectName As String

    Sheets("Base").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set wst = ActiveSheet
    strProjectName = InputBox("Please write the project name")
    wst.Name = strProjectName

    Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Worksheets("Base").Range("O8"), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    wst.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Recording a macro suggests you need something like `subAddress:=wst.name & "!A1"`.

Comment: Or `subAddress:=strProjectName & "!A1"`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add to provide an entire cell reference address. You can't just use the Sheet name, at least that is my understanding.

Anyhow, take a look at this bit of code here.

```
Sub Test()

Dim wst, basesheet As Worksheet
Dim strProjectName As String
Set basesheet = Worksheets("Base")
basesheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Set wst = ActiveSheet
strProjectName = InputBox("Please write the project name")
wst.Name = strProjectName

basesheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=basesheet.Range("O8"), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
wst.Name & "!A1"
```

Something to keep in mind would be the `ActiveSheet` line you have listed. If for whatever reason the sheet changes (either user, or another macro) then this could screw up this entire macro.

Anyhow, the above should do what you want.